# ValueError: Found unexpected instance while processing input tensors for keras functional model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Hi I was meant to create an ensemble model by concatenating output layers from a designed Conv1D and transformer, and I even run each line from concatenate() toward the final dense layer. Everything is fine with expected shape of output for each step until the final stage: Model(inputs, outputs) and I got the error below:

**ValueError: Found unexpected instance while processing input tensors for keras functional model. Expecting KerasTensor which is from tf.keras.Input() or output from keras layer call(). Got: 22**

For Conciseness, I just showed three partial snipped codes for the models I want to combine and the problematic line as follows:

input = (None, 22, 1)

#### Here is the small chunk of output from Conv1D

```
、、、
x = Add()([x, skip])
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling1D(20)(x) 
x = Flatten()(x)
out = Dense(512, activation="relu")(x)
out1 = Dropout(0.5)(out)
return out1
、、、
```

#### Below is the part that return features from Transformer

```
 、、、
for dim in mlp_units:
    x = layers.Dense(dim, activation="relu")(x)
    x = layers.Dropout(mlp_dropout)(x)
    output2 = layers.Dense(7, activation="softmax")(x)
return  out2

   、、、
```

#### This the part output combination and return

```
、、、
def get_model():
inp = Input(input)
out1 = Conv1D(inp)
out2 = Transformer(inp)
conc = concatenate([out1, out2])    
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(conc)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)    
outp = Dense(n_outputs, activation="softmax")(x)

model = Model(inputs=inp ,outputs=outp)
   
return model 
、、、
```

#### and this is where the error was produced:

```
、、、
model = get_model()
、、、
```

Any suggestions and solutions will be appreciated！

Comment: input is a special function in python, it is not a good idea to pass it as a variable to anything.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Thank you for your reply. I tried designing the model without passing my input to Input() function if I understand your advice correctly, but it leads to an error: "TypeError: Dimension value must be integer or None or have an __index__ method, got value 'TensorShape([])"